# Video startar com autoplay, mas com volume em 50% ou mudo!

Tags: javascript, html, css

Minha tag vídeo mostra meus controles de vídeo/áudio perfeitamente. Tudo funcionando.
Mas eu preciso setar o áudio entre 30% e 50% ou até mesmo mudo.
É possível fazer isso com CSS e/ou JS?

```
<video width="960" height="550" controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Seu navegador não suporta o aquivo de vídeo.
</video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para colocar o video ou audio mudo:

```
<video muted id="myVideo">
....
</video>
```

Para controlar o volume utiliza-se javascript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
```

Utilizando jQuery:

```
$("myVideo").prop("volume", 0.5);
```

Fontes: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: Antony, moleza usar o "muted". Vlw pela dica. Ainda estou engatinhando na área. JS ainda é meio confuso pra mim. Mas vlw por ter mostrado as opções. Funcionou só com o MUTED. Ficou assim:   <video width="960" height="550" controls autoplay loop muted> Muito Obrigado.